# JMS single dequeuing for topic

Tags: jms

I have many subscribers listening to a topic, but only one subscriber get the message (dequeing) to process a task.

> Can I go for a topic and non-durable subscribers?

Is the below statement correct:

> A topic will normally deliver the message to the first consumer
>   dequeuing, but if durable subscribers have subscribed to the topic,
>   messages will be delivered to each one of them.

Or queue is a better solution? For me I think publish-subscriber is more simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A message sent to a topic should be delivered to *every* subscriber whether they are durable or not. Of course, this assumes the subscribers are using a blank selector or a selector that matches the message that was sent.